# College problem and I have no idea what to do (Prime numbers)

Tags: python

Im currently in college and I have an assignment that involves multiplying the primes and non primes below 45, so that their product doesn't go over 45. The language is python and I have tried doing for loops and checking for prime and not prime with modulus but I don't know where to go from there. (can't utilize arrays or anything related only loops, while else, elif etc.)

```
for num in range (1, 45):
    if num > 1:
        for num2 in range(2, 45):
            if (num%num2) == 0:
                n = num2
                print(n, 'is Prime')
                if num * num2 < 45:
                    print('Number ', num, '*', num2, '=', num*num2)
```

What exactly im trying to achieve is to first find all the prime numbers, then multiply them by all the non primes. Those primes and non primes are in the range of 1 - 45. Then, I Have to multiply them and their product has to be less than 45 then print that.

UPDATE: So I tried Thanh Tùng Nguyễn's program which is very well built, but I Can't utilize functions since I haven't been taught that (aka would be weird), what I tried to do is simply take what the function is and tried to just implement it into the loops themselves setting n as a boolean value, but my print doesn't amount to anything and I can't catch what's happening. The terminal just stays completely empty. My guess is on the last 'if not' statement, where I have probably written it wrong because I can't understand it myself why it isn't working when im treating it the same as a function through the entire block.

Here's what I got:

```
from math import sqrt

for num1 in range (2, 46):
    if num1 <= 1:
        n = False
    for i in range (2, int(sqrt(num1))):
        if num1%i == 0:
            n = False
    n = True
    if n == True:
        for num2 in range (1, 46):
            if num2 <= 1:
                n = False
            for j in range (2, int(sqrt(num2))):
                if num2%j == 0:
                    n = False
            n = True
            if not n == True:
                if num1 * num2 < 45:
                    print(num1, '*', num2, '=', num1*num2)
```

Comment: This question does not have enough detail for us to answer.  Update the question to include the code you tried, explain what that code did, and explain why that result wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: What exactly im trying to achieve is to first find all the prime numbers, then multiply them by all the non primes. Those primes and non primes are in the range of 1 - 45. Then, I Have to multiply them and their product has to be less than 45 then print that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a prime-number check function like this:

```
from math import sqrt

def checkPrime(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(num))+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Note that you can just check from 2 to √n to optimize it. From there, just find all prime numbers below 45 and multiply it with a non-prime number:

```
from math import sqrt

def checkPrime(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(num))+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

for n in range(2, 45+1):
    if checkPrime(n):
        for j in range(1, 45+1):
            if not checkPrime(j):
                if n * j < 45:
                    print(n, " * ", j, " = ", n*j)
```

Output:

```
2  *  1  =  2
2  *  4  =  8
2  *  6  =  12
2  *  8  =  16
2  *  9  =  18
2  *  10  =  20
2  *  12  =  24
2  *  14  =  28
2  *  15  =  30
2  *  16  =  32
2  *  18  =  36
2  *  20  =  40
2  *  21  =  42
2  *  22  =  44
3  *  1  =  3
3  *  4  =  12
3  *  6  =  18
3  *  8  =  24
3  *  9  =  27
3  *  10  =  30
3  *  12  =  36
3  *  14  =  42
5  *  1  =  5
5  *  4  =  20
5  *  6  =  30
5  *  8  =  40
7  *  1  =  7
7  *  4  =  28
7  *  6  =  42
11  *  1  =  11
11  *  4  =  44
13  *  1  =  13
17  *  1  =  17
19  *  1  =  19
23  *  1  =  23
29  *  1  =  29
31  *  1  =  31
37  *  1  =  37
41  *  1  =  41
43  *  1  =  43
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would there be a way to get a boolean value without the use a function in this case so you can use it only with loops and if's?

Comment: You can use the `sympy` module to check prime numbers. For example, `sympy.isprime(1)` will return `False` and `sympy.isprime(2)` will return `True`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to multiply primes with non-primes.  This means that the products will be formed of 3 or more primes.

To have 3 primes in the product, you can have 2 at most 5 times. You can have 3 at most 3 times, 5 at most twice, 7/11 no more than once.

So you only need to take into account 2, 3, 5, 7 and 11 as primes and combine them in sets of 3 or more without going over 45:

You could nest 5 for-loops for the number of 2s, 3s, 5s, 7s and 11s in the product.

For example:

```
for p2 in range(7):
    for p3 in range(4):
        for p5 in range(3):
            for p7 in range(2):
                for p11 in range(2):
                    prod = 2**p2 * 3**p3 * 5**p5 * 7**p7 * 11**p11
                    if prod > 45 : continue
                    if p2+p3+p5+p7+p11 < 3: continue
                    if p2:  print(2,'x',prod//2,'=',prod)
                    if p3:  print(3,'x',prod//3,'=',prod)
                    if p5:  print(5,'x',prod//5,'=',prod)
                    if p7:  print(7,'x',prod//7,'=',prod)
                    if p11: print(11,'x',prod//11,'=',prod)
```

Output:

```
3 x 15 = 45
5 x 9 = 45
3 x 9 = 27
2 x 21 = 42
3 x 14 = 42
7 x 6 = 42
2 x 15 = 30
3 x 10 = 30
5 x 6 = 30
2 x 9 = 18
3 x 6 = 18
2 x 22 = 44
11 x 4 = 44
2 x 14 = 28
7 x 4 = 28
2 x 10 = 20
5 x 4 = 20
2 x 6 = 12
3 x 4 = 12
2 x 18 = 36
3 x 12 = 36
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 20 = 40
5 x 8 = 40
2 x 12 = 24
3 x 8 = 24
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 16 = 32à
```

You can also do it the other way around, by counting the primes that form each number up to 45 and, if there are 3 or more primes, print the ones that are part of the number as you go:

```
for prod in range(8,46):
    primeCount = 0
    rest = prod
    for prime in range(2,12):
        while rest and rest % prime == 0:
            primeCount += 1
            rest = rest//prime
    if primeCount<3: continue
    if prod%2==0:  print(prod,'=',2,'x',prod//2)
    if prod%3==0:  print(prod,'=',3,'x',prod//3)
    if prod%5==0:  print(prod,'=',5,'x',prod//5)
    if prod%7==0:  print(prod,'=',7,'x',prod//7)
    if prod%11==0: print(prod,'=',11,'x',prod//11)
```

*Note that, even though I'm dividing by non=primes in the counting loop, only primes will actually be counted because, as the `rest` is reduced, multiples of previous primes will no longer divide the rest evenly.*

Output:

```
8 = 2 x 4
12 = 2 x 6
12 = 3 x 4
16 = 2 x 8
18 = 2 x 9
18 = 3 x 6
20 = 2 x 10
20 = 5 x 4
24 = 2 x 12
24 = 3 x 8
27 = 3 x 9
28 = 2 x 14
28 = 7 x 4
30 = 2 x 15
30 = 3 x 10
30 = 5 x 6
32 = 2 x 16
36 = 2 x 18
36 = 3 x 12
40 = 2 x 20
40 = 5 x 8
42 = 2 x 21
42 = 3 x 14
42 = 7 x 6
44 = 2 x 22
44 = 11 x 4
45 = 3 x 15
45 = 5 x 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however that's not what I had ment to be solved, I edited my original question so it can be better understood.